# android - widget attached to a screen border

Tags: android, button, widget

I need to add a Button that is attached to the bottom of the screen so that it remain in that place when scrolling (other widgets move, but this don't). How to do it?

Comment: I don't have a code connected with this thing - I just have no idea how to do it at all

Answer (score 0):

Put everything that you want to scroll in scrollview.
You want that button at the bottom of the layout. Set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in the xml of the button.